# How to show a message dialog before can bring other usercontrol to front

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am developing a WinForms Application , I design a Hamburger Menu app, Lets say I have a "Button1" & "Button2" on the left panel of my app and I have 2 `UserControl`(`userControl1`, `userControl2`) , then when I click the button1, I call `userControl1.BringToFront();`

this is my exact code:

```
        if (!panelUSerControl.Controls.Contains(DashboardView.Instance)) {
            panelUSerControl.Controls.Add(DashboardView.Instance);
            DashboardView.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            DashboardView.Instance.BringToFront();
        } else {
            DashboardView.Instance.BringToFront();
        }
```

So `userControl1` is now displayed on the screen , my question is when I click the button2(this will show `userControl2`), how can I display a confirmation message with option(Yes/No) to inform the user that he/she will leave the `userControl1`? , and if the user selects No, the app will stays in the `userControl1` , and if yes , will show `userControl2`

Thanks in advance,
NicoTing

Comment: you can use messagebox.show() to display a confirmation dialog.

Comment: I updated my question , lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what I did:

```
if (panelUSerControl.Controls.Contains(userControl1.Instance) && panelUSerControl.Controls.GetChildIndex(userControl1.Instance) == 0) {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to cancel your delivery?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No) {
            return;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should do this in your button2 click event, i.e. display a confirmation message there and then proceed to show the second control or not:

```
private void button2_click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Show userControl2?", "Confirmation", 
             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes))
    {
        userControl2.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

There is a "leave" event on each control but this fires when the user has already left the control, so you cannot use it to confirm before leaving the control.

Comment: thanks for the respond , my question is incorrect lol , I will update my question, cause I want to show  a (Yes/No) Option in the dialog , and if the user selects no , the app will stays in the userControl1

Comment: uhhm thanks, I think I should ask a more specific question , sorry , but my issue is I have about 6 user controls , I only want to show a messagedialog in specific control , lets say only if userControl1 is displayed , when I tried to navigate to control 2 or 3 , the mesage will show , but if iam on control2 , then tries to navigate to other control it wont show the message, its like "onnavigatedfrom" from UWP
Thanks

Comment: OK, that seems a different question than what you asked here. If you want navigation like UWP why don't you use WPF instead of WinForms? Also, you may want to take a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms951103.aspx

Comment: Ohh Okay, but its too late if I will make my app wpf , I will try to find another way. Thanks

Comment: Glad to help ;)